# Failing shell script for executing vpk_linux32 with imported libraries, from terminal

Tags: linux, shell, 64-bit

I'm making a shell file, named `vpk.sh`, that'll help me convert folders (with the codes copied from [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/VPK)) into a [vpk file](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/VPK), and accept arguments; so that it wouldn't be as difficult to use it. The first shell file, being:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR=$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(cd "$DIR" && pwd)
exec "$DIR/vpk_linux32" "${@}"
```

is for it being saved in the local directory, as it'll work properly with the commands being `.../vpk.sh "example.vpk"` when executed from the terminal and from any location. The only minor issue is that the folder would be named `example.` instead of `example`.

The issue I'm having with this shell code, being global instead of local, is that I have been trying to fix this myself, only to no avail, with it being saved to `/usr/share/bin/vpk`, meaning that it can be executed from anywhere at any given time:

```
#!/bin/bash
VPK_LINUX=$(find "${HOME}/.local/share/Steam" -type f -iname "vpk_linux32" -print | head -n 1)
VALVE_LIB_DIR=$(dirname "${LINUX_VPK}")
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${VALVE_LIB_DIR}:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}" "$VPK_LINUX" "${1}"
```

however, when I try to execute it, with a vpk file named `example` (giving `example.vpk`), as `vpk "example.vpk"` in the terminal, it would start extracting the vpk file into a folder with it's content extracted, but end up with only extracting the first file it finds, such as `cfg/autoexec.cfg`, but with it being empty instead of having its contents, then immediately stop with the shell outputting an error right after:

```
/usr/local/bin/vpk: line 5:  3071 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${VALVE_LIB_DIR}:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}" "${VPK_LINUX}" "${1}"
```

I'm not sure what's going on, as I'm still learning shell as I code, with knowing that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is possibly an infinite loop, but what is possible to make this file work much better than it's current state?

I apologize for the question if it's sound confusing, as it is my first time asking on here.